# Creating generic update function for Slick 3.1.1

Tags: scala, slick

I have this fucntion:

```
 def updateInvoiceAdminStatusField(id: Int, newAdminStatus: AdminStatus): Future[Int] = {


    db.run {

      val adminStatus: Query[Rep[AdminStatus], AdminStatus, Seq] = InvoicesTable.filter(invoice => invoice.id === id).map(invoice => invoice.status)

      adminStatus.update(newAdminStatus)
    }
  }
```

I thought of making it generic:

```
   def updateInvoiceField[T](id: Int, fieldExtractor: (Invoices) => Rep[T], newValue: T): Future[Int] = {

    db.run {

      val adminStatus = InvoicesTable.filter(invoice => invoice.id === id).map(invoice => {

        fieldExtractor(invoice)
      })

      adminStatus.update(newValue)
    }
  }
```

But this does not compile. Can somebody assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nearly good. With small changes like below it should work:

```
// I added below T: ColumnType
def updateInvoiceField[T: ColumnType](id: Int, fieldExtractor: (Invoices) => Rep[T], newValue: T): Future[Int] = {

  db.run {
      val adminStatus = InvoicesTable.filter(invoice => invoice.id === id).map(invoice => {
          fieldExtractor(invoice)
      })

      adminStatus.update(newValue)
  }
}
```

Notice I added this `: ColumnType` which basically mean you need to have proper implicit in scope - specifically the one that would convert `T` => `ColumnType[T]`. That's simply because otherwise `T` could be anything and `Slick` wouldn't be able to figure out how to convert it.

So for things like `String`, `Int` etc. you obviously have proper conversations already in place (imported from `api` in profile/driver). For you custom types you would need to use `MappedColumnType` to have proper conversion supplied. Example below (typesafe ID):

```
implicit def columnType[T]: BaseColumnType[Id[T]] =
    MappedColumnType.base[Id[T], Long](toLong, fromLong)

private def fromLong[T](dbId: Long): Id[T] = Id(dbId)

private def toLong[T](id: Id[T]): Long = id.value
```